# i have got an error solving this problem from book python with data science?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

`births['day']=births['day'].astype(int)`

i was solving this through jupyter notebook and i am solving is as giving in the book but may be the code change or may be i didn't have the right idea of output to be solved and this should be not done like this..
i don't know please help me solving this query.

i am using dataset births.csv

---

```
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-12-e7a41e4b25cc> in <module>
    ----> 1 births['day']=births['day'].astype(int) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)    5696         else:    5697             # else, only a single dtype is given
    -> 5698             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)    5699             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)    5700  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
        580 
        581     def astype(self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"):
    --> 582         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
        583 
        584     def convert(self, **kwargs): ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, filter, **kwargs)
        440                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
        441             else:
    --> 442                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
        443             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
        444  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
        623             vals1d = values.ravel()
        624             try:
    --> 625                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
        626             except (ValueError, TypeError):
        627                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
        866 
        867         if not np.isfinite(arr).all():
    --> 868             raise ValueError("Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer")
        869 
        870     elif is_object_dtype(arr): ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

Comment: Please provide a title which bettter explains what is your problem.

Comment: `Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer` , your `births['day']` has `NaN` or `Inf` values

Comment: `births['day'] = births['day'].fillna(0)`Doesn't this change the result by looking at replacing NA with 0?

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame seems to contain `nan` values in that column.
So, you might fill those values or remove them before conversion.

Let's fill NaN values with 0 here:

```
births['day'] = births['day'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

For an enlightening reading on **Managing missing Values** in Pandas, refer to this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-missing-data-in-pandas/